# Updating a ProgressDialog's text before dismissing

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a ProgressDialog that is used to display a loading animation along with some text.

It is displayed and removed from within an AsyncTask, and during PostExecute I'm trying to update the ProgressDialog's text with an error message just before dismissing if an error occurs during the AsyncTask's DoInBackground routine.

My problem is that after the text is updated, I need to dismiss the progress dialog, and the updated text doesn't display long enough.

I've tried sleeping the thread, but sleep seems to occur before the view is updated with the text, and so I run into the same issue.

Here is some code:

```
public class LoadRecordTask : AsyncTask
{
    private Activity1 _context;
    private Android.App.ProgressDialog _progressDialog;
    private int _recordId;
    private bool _bSuccess;

    public LoadRecordTask( Activity1 outerActivity, int recordId )
    {
        _context = outerActivity;
        _recordId = recordId;
    }

    protected override void OnPreExecute()
    {
        base.OnPreExecute();

        _progressDialog = Android.App.ProgressDialog.Show( _context , "", "Loading record {0}", _recordId );
    }

    protected override Java.Lang.Object DoInBackground(params Java.Lang.Object[] @params)
    {
        _bSuccess = LoadRecord( _recordId );

        if( !_bSuccess )
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected override void OnPostExecute(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        base.OnPostExecute(result);

        if( !_bSuccess )
        {           
            _progressDialog.SetMessage( "Error loading recording." );
        }

        _progressDialog.Dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you even using an `AsyncTask` when you have all the nice async/await stuff from .NET?

Comment: I will give it a look. I didn't start coding in c#/.net until this android project. I was schooled with c and c++. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Your code can be simplified to very few lines instead of that gnarly `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Handler` instead of `Thread` because Thread.Sleep make Main UI Thread Freeze when you call in `OnPostExecute`. so try it as:

```
  protected override void OnPostExecute(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        base.OnPostExecute(result);

        if( !_bSuccess )
        {           
            _progressDialog.SetMessage( "Error loading recording." );
        }
         Handler hideHandler = new Handler();
         Runnable run = null;
        run = new Runnable (delegate {

        //Dismiss progress bar here
           _progressDialog.Dismiss();
           hideHandler.RemoveCallbacks(run);
        }
       });
       hideHandler.PostDelayed(run, 2000);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `AsyncTask` you are using could be translated to something like:

```
_progressDialog = ProgressDialog.Show( _context , "", "Loading record {0}", _recordId );

if (await LoadRecord(_recordId))
    _progressDialog.Dismiss();
else
    _progressDialog.SetMessage( "Error loading recording." );
```

Where `LoadRecord` could be returning `Task<bool>` and the internals running inside of `Task`. Otherwise you can just wrap the `LoadRecord` method you are currently using in a `Task` to make it run async.

```
private Task<bool> LoadRecord(int recordId)
{
    return Task<bool>.Run(() => 
    {
        //Do stuff here to fetch records
        return true;
    });
}
```

The method you are calling await from needs to be marked as async. I.e.:

```
private async MyAwesomeAsyncMethod() {}
```

Comment: Thanks CB! Here, post that answer here for some street cred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882631/how-to-pose-an-asynctask-in-monodroid-c

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882631/how-to-pose-an-asynctask-in-monodroid-c/21883066#21883066

Answer (score 0):

_view is a private member of the outer activity, Activity1, that the AsyncTask is an inner-class of (in C# there is no implicit reference to the outer class). It is that is set to the root of the layout.

```
protected override void OnPostExecute(Java.Lang.Object result)
{
    base.OnPostExecute(result);

    long millis = 0;

    if( !_bSuccess )
    {
        _progressDialog.SetMessage( "Error loading recording." );       

        millis = 1000;
    }

    _context._view.PostDelayed(()=> {_progressDialog.Dismiss();}, millis);
}
```